# Where is XGrid in Material-UI v5?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I am working on a project that uses Material-UI's **DataGrid**, the project has new requirements and thereby the necessity to use a different component. In the past, I used Material-UI's **XGrid**, I am currently having some issues implementing **XGrid**, and when I searched for the component in MUI's webpage I couldn't find it, **it just disappeared**. It is a little bit tricky to work around the issue as there is no documentation.

I also found a new component (**DataGridPro**) which seems to be the replacement for **XGrid**, my questions here are: what happened to **XGrid**? is my license still valid for **DataGridPro**?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems that the **XGrid** has been renamed to **DataGridPro**, you can find more info here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/releases/tag/v4.0.0

Answer (score 3):

As [@carlos neisa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69243856/what-happened-with-material-uis-xgrid#comment122406329_69243856) pointed out, they changed the name from `XGrid` to `DataGridPro`. From [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/2313) issue:

> We are making a change to the terminology used in the project to support the long-term direction. The high-level bit is that we are going to use `x-` as a prefix for the rich/advanced components and `-pro` as a suffix for the paid professional version.
>
> Current:
>
> - `@material-ui/data-grid` DataGrid MIT
> - `@material-ui/x-grid` XGrid Commercial
>
> Target:
>
> - `@mui/x-data-grid` DataGrid MIT
> - `@mui/x-data-grid-pro` DataGridPro Commercial
> - `@mui/x-tree-view` TreeView MIT
> - `@mui/x-tree-view-pro` TreeViewPro Commercial

**Before:**

```
import { XGrid } from '@material-ui/x-grid';
```

**After:**

```
import { DataGridPro } from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro';
```